# How does symmetry of half filled and fully filled orbitals lead to stability

Tags: quantum-chemistry, atoms

I googled a lot about why symmetry of half filled and fully filled orbitals decreases their energy but every time it is repeated that symmetry leads to stability. So the question is why symmetry leads to stability? What is the actual logic behind it?

Comment: Symmetry does not lead to stability. In some cases, when your orbital is half-filled, certain kinds of symmetry lead to _instability_ (see [Jahn-Teller effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jahn%E2%80%93Teller_effect)). In other cases, symmetry is mostly irrelevant to stability.

Comment: Actually in the books I have read and also on the internet, "symmetry" word is used widely for accounting the stability without any explanation "Why" . Thank You for reply.